# Converting varchar values to a primary key in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I'm pretty new with mysql and databases in general so forgive the simplicity of this. I have a excel/csv spreadsheet with 13,000 rows that contains the following fields "Bandname | Song Title | MP3Link" (Not actual fields, I simplified this for the point of illustration).

I wish to convert this to a mysql database so I can display songs on my site grouped by Bandname. Obviously I have multiple rows of data of songs from the same bands.

For a functioning database that performs well I am guessing that ideally I would have a separate table with just the bandnames in it (let's call it the "Bandname" table) and an auto-incrementing primary key "bandnameID". Then I am guessing that my "Songname" table would have a column containing that key to look this up.

Questions...

1. I am guessing that this 2 table format would perform significantly faster (given that I have 13,000 records) when looking up all songs by AC/DC than it would do if it was looking through a single table - is this correct or wrong?
2. If I do separate my data out into 2 tables, how do I cycle through the "SongName" table to convert all instances of say the value "AC/DC" to the correct foreign key "13"  without cross-referencing and typing it manually for each Band which would take forever?
3. I do have a separate list of all of the band names without duplicates - could I just have that list of varchar data and use it as a primary key to lookup songs by that particular artist? Would there be any point in that over a single table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1: performance and normalization**
The primary goal of normalization is **not** performance but:

- avoidance of modification anomalies
- easier extendability
- readablity
- more suitability for a wide range of different queries

More information:
[Wikipedia - Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)
[How to Deal with SQL Modification Anomalies and Normal Forms](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-deal-with-sql-modification-anomalies-and-no.html)

**Question 2: insert**
There are many ways to do this, here's one:

- Import the spreadsheet in a table, let's say `temp_songs`
- Import the bands into the `bands` table
- Create an empty table `songs` with `FOREIGN KEY` to `bands`
- do a `INSERT INTO songs SELECT ...` query with `temp_songs` and `JOIN` the `bands` table on band name. This way you can get the referencing keys right ([MySQL - INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html))

**Question 3: table `band`**
*could I just have that list of varchar data and use it as a primary key to lookup songs by that particular artist?*

Technically you could just store it in a column but if you want to store the info in the database the most logical choice is a separate table which I strongly suggest (see answer to question 1).

Comment: Thanks, this was useful, however I cannot get my head around the correct syntax "do a INSERT INTO songs SELECT ... query with temp_songs and JOIN the bands table on band name. This way you can get the referencing keys right " could you by any chance offer an example please?

Comment: Something like this - Tables: `temp_songs(band_name, song_title, mp3link`, `songs(id, song_title, mp3link, band_id)`, `bands(id, band_name)`. Query: `INSERT INTO songs (song_title, mp3link, band_id) SELECT temp_songs.song_title, temp_songs.mp3link, bands.id FROM temp_songs JOIN bands ON temp_songs.band_name = bands.band_name`